# indy TIdHTTPP socket error #110004 bad adress

Tags: delphi-7, indy, idhttp

I am trying to get result from yahoo search and save those result into file. However, there is an Exception while i use IdHTTP.Get it shows 'Exception, Socket Error # 10014 Bad address.'. below is my code:

```
function TfrmIdHTTP.GetYahooSearch(const aSearch: String;
 var aResponse: String): Boolean;
var
   mHost, mPath, mQuery  : String;
   mResult, mStrBlock    : String;
   mQueryStream  : TStringStream;
   mResultStream : TStringStream;
begin

   Result := False;

   Try
     pbStatus.Position := 10;

     mHost := 'http://www.yahoo.com';
     mPath := '/';
     mQueryStream  := TStringStream.Create('');
     mResultStream := TStringStream.Create('');

     IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
     IdHTTP.Request.ContentType :=  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

     pbStatus.Position := 30;


     IdHTTP.Get(mHost + mPath, mResultStream);

showmessage('1');
     mResult := mResultStream.DataString;

     SaveFile('yahoo_search_01.htm', mResult, True);

     pbStatus.Position := 50;

     mStrBlock := StringCrop(mResult, '<form', '</form>',1);

     if PosEx('role="search"', mStrBlock) = 0 then
     begin
      aResponse := 'Error, please check and try again later';
      Exit;
     end;

     pbStatus.Position := 70;

     mHost := 'http://www.yahoo.com';
     mPath := '/search';
     mQuery := 'toggle=' + Utf8ToAnsi(StringCrop(mStrBlock, 'name="toggle" value="', '">', 1))
        + '&cop='   + Utf8ToAnsi(StringCrop(mStrBlock, 'name="cop" value="', '">', 1))
        + '&ei='    + Utf8ToAnsi(StringCrop(mStrBlock, 'name="ei" value="', '">', 1))
        + '&.tsrc=' + Utf8ToAnsi(StringCrop(mStrBlock, 'name=".tsrc" value="', '">', 1))
        + '&p='     + Utf8ToAnsi(Trim(edtSearch.Text))
        ;

        mQueryStream.WriteString(mQuery);
        pbStatus.Position := 90;

        IdHTTP.Post(mHost + mPath, mQueryStream, mResultStream);

        mResult := mResultStream.DataString;

        SaveFile('yahoo_search_02.htm', mResult, True);

  Except
    on E:Exception do begin
      aResponse := Format('%s, %s', ['Exception', e.Message]);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  aResponse := mResult;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: 10014 is `WSAEFAULT`, which means an invalid **memory address** is being passed to a Winsock function.  But there is no way to diagnose that without knowing which function is failing, and what the call stack leading up to the error looks like. You are using a very old version of Delphi, are you at least using an up-to-date version of Indy?

Comment: Assigning a `ContentType` for a `GET` request is useless. You should use the versions of `Get()`/`Post()` that return a `string` instead of filling a `TStringStream` to read its `DataString`. For your `/search` query, you should use the version of `Post()` that takes a `TStrings` as input, as you are not formatting the query string correctly (you are not percent-encoding reserved characters and non-ASCII characters). You are also not clearing `mResultStream` between each request, so you are going to append the second response to the end of the first response. Is that what you really want?

Comment: I'm using Indy 9.0.18. btw, what is the latest version of indy?

Comment: That is quite old, even for Indy 9. The last version of 9 was 9.0.50 or so, IIRC. The current version is 10.6.2.5410